# Let $f:\mathbb{R \rightarrow R}$ satisfies $f(x)+f(y)= f \biggl(\frac{x+y}{1-xy}\biggl)$ and $f'(0)=5$. Then find $f(x)$

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, partial-derivative, inverse-function

> > Let $f:\mathbb{R \rightarrow R}$ satisfies $f(x)+f(y)= f \biggl(\frac{x+y}{1-xy}\biggl)$ and $f'(0)=5$. Then find $f(x)$

**Teacher's Method:**

He differentiated the whole function with respect to $x$ as follow

$f^{\prime}(x)+f^{\prime}(y) \cdot \frac{dy}{dx}=f^{\prime}(\frac {x+y}{1-xy}) \cdot \biggl(\frac{\big(1-xy\big)\big(1+\frac{dy}{dx}\big)+\big(x+y\big)\big(x\frac{dy}{dx}+y\big)}{\big(1-xy\bigl)^2}\biggl)$

And he put $\frac{dy}{dx}=0$ stating that $x$ and $y$ are independent
and finally he obtained the result $f(x)=5\tan^{-1}(x)$

**My Doubt:**

why $x$ and $y$ are independent?

finally we are obtaining the result $y=5\tan^{-1}(x)$
$\;$then how can they be independent?

**My second Doubt:** why above method is not working for $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$

**I know what is the other method to solve this Question but my doubt is as mentioned above.**

Comment: It works the same way $f'(x+y) =f'(x) $ put $x=0$ and $f'(y) =f'(0)$ so $f(y) = yf'(0)$

Comment: As for why they are independent, the functional relation is supposed to hold for all $x, y$ so in particular it works for independent $x, y$.

Comment: You should have more doubts, since the real arctangent does not satisfy that functional relation on the whole of its domain (what if $x$ and $y$ are $2$, say)?

Comment: Here $x$ and $y$ are just two arbitrary (independent)  real values of  $x$ one may rather say $x_1$ and $x_2$, $y$is not like $y=f(x)$.

Comment: x and y are independent because we chose them so. As to why we did that, the answer is: because we could. Also, your statement that $y=5\tan^{-1}(x)$ is not true.

Answer (score 6):

$$f(x)+f(y)= f \biggl(\frac{x+y}{1-xy}\biggl)$$
Let $x=0=y$, then $2f(0)=f(0) \implies f(0)=0$. Next Let $y=-x$ \implies $f(-x)=-f(x)$
$$f'(x)=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}==\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+h)+f(-x)}{h}$$
$$\implies f'(x)=\lim_{h\to 0}f\left(\frac{h}{1-x^2-xh}\right)\frac{1}{h}\left(\frac{h}{1+x^2+xh}\right)^{-1}\left(\frac{h}{1+x^2+xh}\right)$$
$$\implies f'(x)=\left(\frac{1}{1+x^2}\right)\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{f(z)}{z}=\frac{f'(0)}{1+x^2}=\frac{5}{1+x^2}.$$
Integrating, we get $$f(x)=5\tan^{-1} x+C, f(0)=0 \implies f(x)=5 \tan^{-1} x$$

Comment: But this is not what the OP is asking for!? The OP is not looking for a different method but a justification of the used method

Comment: Thanks, I have now added one point in my comment to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Substitute $x=\tan u , y= \tan v$ then we obtain $$f(\tan u) +f(\tan v) = f(\tan (u+v) ).$$
If we denote $$F(z) =f(\tan z)$$
and we obtain $$F(u) +F(v) =F(u+v).$$
So if we assume that $f$ is continous then we obtain $$F(x) = ax $$ for some $a.$
Hence
$$f(x) = a\arctan x$$
and since $f'(0) = 5$ thus $a=5.$

This proof does not need differentiability of $f.$

Comment: I know other method to solve this question. I just wanted to know why he said $x$ and $y$ are independent.

Answer (score 1):

The given functional equation is to be read as : "for any two $x_1,x_2$ belonging to the domain of $f(x)$, the functional equation holds."

Instead of $x_1,x_2$, labels $x,y$ are used. These are independent variables. So $dy/dx=0$ or $dx_2/dx_1=0$ is true.

The last solution obtained is $f(x)=5tan^{-1}x$ which is unfortunately written as $y=f(x)=...$. Ofcourse the label $y$ for $f(x)$ is not the same as label $y$ for $x_1,x_2$ (or $x,y$). $y=f(x)$ is dependent variable.

Comment: Is this answer helpful? @mathophile

Answer (score 0):

I think what he did is take a partial derivative wrt x and then plug $x=0$,it becomes $$f'(x)=\left(\dfrac{1+y^2}{(1-xy)^2}\right)\cdot f'\left(\dfrac{x+y}{1-xy}\right)\implies f'(0)=\dfrac{f'(y)}{1+y^2}$$
which gives the solution $f(x)=5\arctan{x}+c$.PLugging back into the original assertion we get $c=0$ hence $f(x)=5\arctan(x)$

Actually this and what your sir did are just the same,basically we just put $y=$ something fixed and then differentiated wrt $x$ in crude terms.Thats why we can ignore the $\dfrac{dy}{dx}=0$.I hope I am making sense(This is what taking a partial derivative is)