# If $f(\frac{x}{y})=\frac{f(x)}{f(y)}$ for all $x,y \in \Bbb R$ , $y \neq 0$ and $f'(x)$ exist for all all $x$ , $f(2)=4$, Then $f(5)$ is?

Tags: limits, derivatives

> > If $f\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)=\frac{f(x)}{f(y)}$ for all $x,y \in \Bbb R$ , $y \neq 0$ and $f'(x)$ exist for all $x$ , $f(2)=4$,  Then $f(5)$ is?

I am solving this question using my teacher's method which is as follows

**My Approach:**

Differentiate with respect to $x$ assuming $y$ to be constant

$f'\left(\frac{x}{y}\right) \cdot \frac{1}{y}=\frac{f'(x)}{f(y)}$

But i am not sure how to processed further using this method to get the result because i am not given any derivative.

**I know definition method to solve this question**

**Here is the question which has been solved using direct differentiation** [Let $f:\mathbb{R \rightarrow R}$ satisfies $f(x)+f(y)= f \biggl(\frac{x+y}{1-xy}\biggl)$ and $f'(0)=5$. Then find $f(x)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4248361/let-f-mathbbr-rightarrow-r-satisfies-fxfy-f-biggl-fracxy1-xy/4248392#4248392)

**P.S.:- I've solved many question using direct differentiation method but I am not getting above question**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hints: Let us restrict $f$ to $(0,\infty)$. Differentiate w.r.t $x$ then w.r.t. $y$ and conlude that $\frac {xf'(x)} {f(x)}=\frac {yf'(y)} {f(y)}$. [Note that $f(y) \neq 0$ for all $y \neq 0$. This is imlpied in the given equation]. From this conclude that each side is a constant and then show that  $f(x)=x^{b}$ for some $b$. Now $f(2)=4$ gives $b=2$. Hence $f(5)=25$.

ALternative solution: Actually differentiability is not required; continuity of $f$ is enough! The given equation is equivalent to $f(uv)=f(u)f(v)$. Continuous solutions of this equation (related to Cauchy's equation) are of the form $f(x)=|x|^{c}$.

Comment: Actually I think the solutions are $f(x)=|x|^b$ ($b > 1$) or $f(x)=x |x|^c$ ($c \geq 0$). But this doesn't matter for the answer, since we can ignore $x<0$ values.

Comment: @ascheplerThank you for the comment. I have corrected the answer.