# Functional equation $f (\frac{x}{y} )= \frac{f(x)}{f(y)}$ f(2) = 4. Find $\lim_{n_\to inf} \sum_{i=0}^n (e^{r/n})f\frac{r ^ {1/2}}{n}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions

Functional equation $f (\frac{x}{y} )= \frac{f(x)}{f(y)}$ for all x, y in R, f' (x) exists for all x, f(2) = 4. Find $\lim_{n_\to inf} \sum_{i=0}^n (e^{r/n})f(\frac{r ^ {1/2}}{n})$

See also [If $f(\frac{x}{y})=\frac{f(x)}{f(y)}$ for all $x,y \in \Bbb R$ , $y \neq 0$ and $f'(x)$ exist for all all $x$ , $f(2)=4$, Then $f(5)$ is?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4275439/if-f-fracxy-fracfxfy-for-all-x-y-in-bbb-r-y-neq-0-and)

There are two parts to the equation, evaluating the functional equation and then evaluating the limit of the sum.

Now, for the first part, I have obtained f(0) = 0, f(1) = 1, and $f'\left(\frac{x}{y}\right) \cdot \frac{1}{y}=\frac{f'(x)}{f(y)}$. Substituting y = x, I get $f'\left(1\right) \cdot \frac{1}{x}=\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}$. If I knew the value of f'(1) as was given in a variant of the problem (f'(1) = 2), I would have been able to proceed further.

Instead, the value that I have is of f(2) instead of f'(1). How do I evaluate f(x) from here?

Further, in the sum, does it turn into a definite integral? How is the sum evaluated, if it is not a definite integral?

Comment: $f'(x)/f(x)=c/x$ gives $f(x)=x^{c}$. Since $f(2)=4$ we get  $c=2$ and $f(x)=x^{2}$.

Comment: Thank you! The functional equation part is resolved. How do we solve the limit of the sum, though?

Comment: You can compute the sum explicitly.

Comment: Your brevity is reassuring, but I am not even sure how to proceed. Without the coefficients, the sum is a GP, but each term is a product of one term of an AP and one term of a GP. Are you pointing to the sum of an AGP?

Comment: $\sum_i it^{i}$ can be computed using the fact that  $\sum_i it^{i-1}$ is the derivative of $\sum_i t^{i}$ and the latter is a geometric sum.

Comment: I see. But what is the relation between the two series? $ \sum t^i$ is $t \cdot \frac {\left(t^n - 1 \right)}{\left(t - 1\right)}. $ The general term of the first series is a derivative wrt t of this series. But is the derivative meaningful when we consider the series, with all variables marked? Can you give a more elaborate explanation of this step? I don't understand how the derivative works with given terms instead of variables. By the way, the first series $it^i$ is an AGP, and it has an explicit formula, so it can be calculated if the AGP sum formula is given.